# how to initialize a default one2many fields in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

"python code for account_invoice.py and i want to know how to initialize a default one2many fields in  OpenERP "

```
class account_invoice(osv.osv):

  def _tax_line_default(self, cr ,uid, context=None):
        obj= self.pool.get('account.invoice.tax')
        ids= obj.search(self, cr, uid)
  obj.write(cr, uid, ids[0], {'name' : 'droit de timbre','amount':0.400})
  res =obj.browse(cr, uid, ids[0])
 return res.name_get(cr, uid, ids[0], context)

_ columns = {

 'tax_line': fields.one2many('account.invoice.tax', 'invoice_id', 'Tax Lines', readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)]})
}
_defaults = {
'tax_line':_tax_line_default,
}



     http://nsa33.casimages.com/img/2013/05/17/130517043059690422.png

     http://nsa33.casimages.com/img/2013/05/17/130517053356530066.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return list of IDs from your function like this `return [res.id]`

You have to remove `self` from search method. That is the reason of your error.

```
ids = obj.search(cr, uid, [])
```

This is my suggestion as per your code.

Comment: Hello, I want to assign default value to one2many field but as per above way my function doesn't get called. Is there any thing else i need to keep in mind? Thanx.